# How can i implement continuos delivery pipeline for java liberty in IBM CLOUD (Bluemix)

Tags: java, maven, ibm-cloud

I'm trying implement a continuos delivery pipeline in java liberty project, now I'm using the git tool etc. However When I did a one update to my code, The continuos delivery doesn't create the new war file inside my folder target.

POM.xml

`
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>net.wasdev.maven.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>java7-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>buyatibm-dev</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Liberty Profile Sample - Servlet</name>
<url>https://wasdev.github.io</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/WASdev/sample.servlet/master/LICENSE</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <warName>buyatibm-dev</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.wasdev.wlp.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <configFile>src/main/wlp/server.xml</configFile>
                <bootstrapProperties>
                    <appLocation>../../../../../${project.build.finalName}</appLocation>
                </bootstrapProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Manifest.yml

`---applications:
- name: buyatibm-dev-jltn
  random-route: true
  memory: 256M
  path: ./target/buyatibm-dev.war`

Answer (score 0):

Continuos Delivery will not update the war present in target folder. You need to right click on the project- Run As - Maven install to update the contents. Once you commit the changes to git, then continous delivery should act.

Answer (score 0):

Reference the following starter kit as an example:

https://console.bluemix.net/developer/appservice/starter-kits/java-microprofile-java-ee-microservice

Click the **Deploy to Cloud** button (choosing CF/Kube as the deployment option), and it will show you an example of how to set up your project.